# Why isn't this PHP script actually adding rows to the database?

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php 
    session_start(); 

    //Obtain data from register page
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];

    //Check to see user has input 
    if ($username !=''  || $password !='' || $confirmpassword !='' || $email !='') {

        if ($password1 == $password2) {

            // connect to database
            $db = new mysqli('removed', 'removed','removed' ,'removed');

            // Check to see if connection was successful    
            if ($db->connect_errorno) {
                die ('Sorry, we are having some issues with our database. We should be back online soon.');
        }

            // Prepare statement
            $query = "INSERT INTO  `database`.`users` (
`id` ,
`minecraftusername` ,
`email` ,
`password` ,
`joined` ,
`rank`
)
VALUES (
NULL ,  ?,  ?,  ?, NOW( ) ,  '1'
);";
            $stmt=$db->prepare($query);
            $stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $email, $password);
            //Execute query
            $stmt->execute();
            // header("Location: ../default.php"); 
            echo 'You have successfully registered an account!';
        } else {
            // header("Location: ../default.php"); 
            echo 'Passwords do not match.';
        }
    } else {
        // header("Location: ../default.php"); 
        echo 'Please fill out all the fields';

    }
?>
```

When you try to register, it does echo the registered successfully message, but when I go to phpmyadmin the number of rows hasn't changed.

I am really not sure what errors I have made.

Any help would really be appreciated.

Comment: Check the php error log.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin's rowcount isn't accurate all the time. Do the rows appear when you choose to browse the database table directly?

Comment: 6 inserts and 3 binds (?)

Comment: Your database connection is inside the password condition. That's the problem.

Comment: I see something fishy... on one line you use $password and $confirmpassword, on the next $password1 and $password2. Maybe the second `if` test fails because of this??

Comment: @CodeBird inserting NULL for primary key is common if it is autoincrement

Comment: @RobP thanks for the info, didn't know, I prefer not inserting anything and typing less... will delete my comment

Comment: Where are `$confirmpassword`, `$password1` and `$password2` set?

Comment: you might want to check the return values for `prepare()`, `bind_param()` and `execute()` functions and based on that you can narrow down the problem.

Comment: Wow- probably the most errors ever ! Thanks a lot guys :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$password = $_POST['password'];
```

Here you set only `$password`, but then you expect other variables to exist,

```
if ($username !=''  || $password !='' || $confirmpassword !='' || $email !='') {
    if ($password1 == $password2) {
```

`$confirmpassword` and `$password1` and `$password2` are never set. Noted in comments by @RobP and @Ali.

You connect to the database only if `$password1 == $password2`, and you only `die()` in that block as well. So you might easily skip that whole block, and not `die()`, and go on to try to run the INSERT without having connected to the database. Noted in comment from @Erico.

```
if ($db->connect_errorno) {
```

It's [connect_errno](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect-errno.php), not "connect_errorno". If that block of code were run, it would generate a notice: `PHP Notice:  Undefined property: mysqli::$connect_errorno`. So this proves that your code to connect to the database was never run.

```
$stmt=$db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param('sss', $username, $email, $password);
$stmt->execute();
```

You should always check the return value of [prepare()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) and [execute()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php). They return **false** if there is any problem with the statement. Like if you had a syntax error, or violated a unique constraint or something. Right now your INSERT might be failing but you'll never know. Also noted in a comment by @sanketh.

Or else you can set [mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT)](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php) to raise exceptions if there's an error. Then you don't need to write code to check the return values, because your script will die if there's any mysqli error. You have to set this report mode *before* you connect to the database.

Also, you never set a value for `$username`.

Comment: Thank you so much :) I should have noticed that.... I cut and pasted from my login page that worked fine....